# Is it possible to call a method from an intent?

Tags: java, android, methods, proximity

Is it possible to call a method from an `Intent`?
I need to call an notification method that I build and it has to be in this activity.

```
Intent locationNotific = new Intent("SendProximityIntent");
locationNotific.putExtra("RowID", id);
sendBroadcast(locationNotific);
PendingIntent lPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, 
    locationNotific, 0);

lm.addProximityAlert((double) locationAlertGeoP.getLatitudeE6(),
    (double) locationAlertGeoP.getLongitudeE6(), 
    (float) 999999999,(long) 100000, lPendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can put an extra field the intent with a specific value. When the activity starts, parse the extra field and, if the value is found, call the desired method. Something like:

```
    localNotific.putExtra("KEY_METHOD_TO_CALL", 1);
```

And in your activity:

```
onCreate... {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int value = -1;
    if (null != intent) {
        value = intent.getIntExtra("KEY_METHOD_TO_CALL", -1);
    }
    if (-1 != value) {
        //Call your method here
    }

}
```

Hope this help.